# jquery flot xaxis how to make labels go under the chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot, axis-labels

I have a chart that is being generated using `flot`. Due to large variation in data and a lot of columns I get following:

[image]

where some names are longer when columns and they start covering them. I am trying now to move names so they would stay under the chart.

mechanism I am using ATM

```
function onCancellationAgentsReceived(series) {
        $("#agentcancellations").empty();
        $.plot("#agentcancellations", [series], { bars: { show: true, align: "center" }, xaxis: { mode: "categories", tickLength: 0, position :"bottom",   } });
    }
```

**How do I move labels under the chart?**

Comment: you can roteate the x-axis label, so this problem will be solved. For that please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634594/flot-bar-chart-xaxis-label-with-rotated-text-by-90-alignment-issue

Comment: not gonna cut it I need labels to go under at 90 angle.