# Organizing stick axis labels on Flot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I'm using a Flot chart and when I have many labels in the xaxis so the information is truncated.
[image]

I need to change the labels angle to show the information correctly, like this:
[image]

How can I do this? I read something about `labelAngle: 45` property for xaxis, but that does not work. When I use this property nothing changes in the graph.

```
xaxis: {
        show: true,
        mode: "time", 
        ticks: xaxisLabel,
        //timeformat:"%d/%m/%y %H:%M",
        timeformat: ( ($('#periodo').val() == "0") || ($('#periodo').val() == "1"))?"%H:%M":"%d/%m/%y",
        timezone: "browser",
        tickSize: [4, 'hour']
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flot does not support rotated labels by default. You need to define some custom CSS (like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639178/2610249)) or use a plugin, for example [tickrotor](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor) (which uses the `xaxis.rotateTicks` property instead of `labelAngle`).

Comment: One question... when I'm using tickrotor plugin, the vertical line from grid not appears, just horizontal line. How to resolve it?

Comment: Have you specified the [ticklength](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) property?